# Taking textfield input and inserting it into a picker in swift 5.1

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield, picker

I'm working through a beginner project that deals with pickers in swift 5.1.
Currently, I have a picker with some names and two buttons named Insert and Replace.
I would like the user to be able to enter a name into a text field and have that name be added
to the picker if the user presses the insert button or have that name replace the currently selected name
in the picker if the user presses the replace button. Below it the code that I currently have.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    private let selectNames = [ "Charles", "Tim", "Bob", "Kim", "Lisa"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBAction func onSelectPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let row = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selected = selectNames[row]
        let title = "You Selected \(selected)!"

        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: title,
            message: "Thank you for choosing",
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(
            title: "You're welcome",
            style: .default,
            handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    //MARK:-
    // MARK: Picker Data Source Methods

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int { return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int { return selectNames.count
    }

    // MARK: Picker Delegate Methods

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? { return selectNames[row]

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the insert button you'd create a function that takes the uitextfields string and adds it to the selectNames array.

Then use selctNames.Count for number of rows.

refresh the picker in the function thats used on the insert button.